# Как скрыть на время загрузки jquery все div id которые получаются после парсинга страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

как сделать такую возможность, после перезагрузки сайта элементы которые получаются после парсинга jquery, прыгают, то есть там еще не появилась информация и после работы скрипта она появляется. Так вот, как вывести в такие элементы прелоадер, например иконку загрузки и т.д.? Чтобы пользователь изначально видел загружающийся элемент, а уже потом все загруженные div id, которые подгружаются с другой страницы сайта.

Comment: Запускаете функцию обертку после загрузки страницы, которая вешает на контент который надо спрятать class = 'hide' и который будет выводить анимацию загрузки, внутри этой функции  запускаете синхронно ваш jquery, после jquery убираете 'hide'

Comment: так и поставьте туда прям в верстку иконку свою загрузки. получите контент - замените его целиком в блоке, убрав этим иконку свою.

Comment: @teran Я уже так пробовал, но есть некоторые решения, которые используют в блоках подгрузки другие DIV, которые после загрузки меняются. То есть, в <div id="js">Лежит блок, который изначально задумывался для пользователя</div>, но после подгрузки, он изменяется на блок для гостей. Так вот, если добавить загрузку, то файл просто покажет весь контент и только потом покажет элемент.